# How to make arrow pointing down show the background instead of having a color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background

I have created an arrow pointing down from a bootstrap jumbotron with video background like this:

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVVVK.jpg)

I'm not sure if it'd be possible but can I make the arrow show the video in the background instead of being colored?

This is the code to create the arrow:

```
.jumbotron::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 90.9%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

This is HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="index-jumbotron">
  <div id="container">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="{% static 'videos/fun.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for the jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron{
    background: no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron #container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 580px;
    background: #edeae8;
    margin: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron #container video{
    width: 110%;
}
```

Comment: This may be help you: http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/EaKPMK

Comment: thanks, i ended up using it and it looks good.